# install linux os on lenovo ideapad miix 310

Tags: linux, ubuntu, touch-screen, tablet

I already tried to install Ubuntu and Mint on my tablet and it almost worked, I just had problems getting auto rotation to work.

The main problem is that there appear some kind of striations, e.g. at boot, Ubuntu displays the "Ubuntu" logo and first it looks okay, but like every second there appears a blurred "Ubuntu" .5 inch lower and if it reaches the bottom, it continues on top until it looks like some kind of spacey wheel stamp.

The same problem appears if Ubuntu is running, but here it happens with every point on the display where the color is white and I have no idea where it comes from.

I already read somewhere it might be because of the bios/uefi version, but I already tried other versions. I currently run on 1HCN42WW and already tried 1HCN30WW and also 1HCN33WW

Specifications:

it's a Lenovo IdeaPad Miix 310-10ICR running on Windows 10

CPU is an Intel Atom Z8350, 4 GB RAM and a 64 GB emmc storage

Has anyone experienced similar things with a tablet or does someone have an idea what could cause this strange graphical behavior?

Could the lack of a graphics card be a problem? Whereas I think theres something like an onboard graphics on the intel chip, but I'm not sure.

that's what it looks like after I tried Ubuntu, the desktop of the os also looks similarly messed up:
[image]

Comment: Since 18.04 it boots fine with bluetooth not working and as far as I remember the volume buttons not working as well. However, since 18.10 everything works. I've got the exact same model with 18.10 working just fine.